# requirejs optimizer - need help optimizing our application

Tags: javascript, build, requirejs, optimization, grunt-contrib-requirejs

We have a large scale javascript application that we are trying to concatenate and minify using grunt-contrib-requirejs. We use the Aura framework. We use bower to pull in dependencies from other repositories into our main application.

Here is our **app structure**

```
- app/  
   |  
   |_ main.js  
   |_ index.html  
   |_ css
   |_ bower_components/  
      |_ core/
      |_ widget1/  
          |_ main.js  
          |_ views/  
          |_ models/  
      |_ widget2/  
      |_ extension1/  
      |_ extension2/  
      |_ other third party libraries, etc
- Gruntfile.js
- bower.json
```

**main.js:**

```
requirejs.config({
    shim: {
        ...
    },
    paths: {
       'core': 'bower_components/core/app/main',
       'aura': 'bower_components/aura/dist/',
       'jquery': 'bower_components/jquery/jquery',
       'backbone': ...,
       ... lots of other paths
    }
});
define(['core', 'jquery', 'jqueryui'], function(core, $) {
    // Here we start Aura, which finds our extensions and widgets in
    // bower_components
});
```

Our current **requirejs task** config:

```
requirejs: {
    compile: {
        options: {
            mainConfigFile: 'app/main.js',
            name: 'main',
            include: ['bower_components/widget1/main', 'bower_components/widget2/main',
                'bower_components/extension1/main', 'bower_components/extension2/main'],
            exclude: ['jquery'],
            insertRequire: ['main'],
            out: 'dist/app.js'
        }
    }
}
```

This concats our app/main and its dependencies, but when we try to run it, we get errors like:
    GET http://www.my-machine:8080/bower_components/underscore/underscore.js 404 (Not Found)
even though underscore is a dependency of many of the widgets we include.

We have extensively tried different options in [the r.js examples](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js), and read through many stackover flow issues trying to find an answer.
We want advice on how to build this into one minified file with this structure:

**UPDATE #2**: Correct file structure

```
- dist/  
    |_ index.html // copied using grunt copy
    |_ css        // copied using grunt copy
    |_ app.js     // Built with grunt requirejs
```

**UPDATE**
We have included `underscore` in our shim which fixed the above error, but we're still getting another error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://my-machine.com:8080/bower_components/core/app/main.js
```

This is included in the minimized file so I don't understand why it can't find that file:

```
define("bower_components/core/app/main.js", ["aura/aura", "bootstrap"], function(){
...
});
```

**UPDATE #3**
The define above came from the file generated by the optimization tool! The original define for that module, `core/app/main.js`, looks like:

```
define(['aura', 'bootstrap'], function(Aura) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: have you included underscore in shim ?

Comment: could you please update description of you code structure and share built file

Comment: btw, i've used one trick to clarify with paths - after build i've included this script in page require.config({ baseUrl: '/path/to/scripts' }). Anyway, to help you i need you to share built file + full file structure.

Answer (score 3):

You mention having this in your optimized file:

```
define("bower_components/core/app/main.js", ["aura/aura", "bootstrap"], function(){
...
});
```

But this does not make sense. If I reproduce a structure similar to what you show in your question and run an optimization on it then the file located at `bower_components/core/app/main.js` is optimized as:

```
define("core", ...
```

because it is known as `core` to the rest of your application due to the `paths` setting `'core': 'bower_components/core/app/main'`.

I can reproduce the incorrect module name if I add `'bower_components/core/app/main.js'` to the `include` setting in the build configuration. When I add this name to the `include` list, I also get the loading error you mentioned. Make sure that your `include` list does not contain this name, and make sure that there is nothing anywhere which lists `'bower_components/core/app/main.js'` as a dependency. This name should not appear in any `define` or `require` call.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of considerations first:

First of all, you should avoid defining module with a name. The name is to be generated by the optimization tool normally. Please read here: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulename

Second, you should understand what the baseUrl is and when it's used to located resources. The baseUrl seems to be "app/" in your case although you have not defined it explicitly. You should read this also: 
http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-baseUrl
So if you use the ".js" extension, then the baseUrl won't be taken into account.

Now what you should try:

To start with, remove the first argument "bower_components/core/app/main.js" from define function. Then you should refer to this module by auto-generated module id that will be a path relative to the baseUrl without ".js" extension.

Comment: 1. Are you referring to `define("bower_components/core/app/main.js", ["aura/aura", "bootstrap"], function(){
        ...
    });`?
I wasn't clear - that *was* created by the optimization tool - I copied and pasted that from the file it generated.

Comment: I also tried adding "baseUrl: 'app/'" in two different spots (in our requirejs.config and in the requirejs compile task), and neither fixed the problem. Our requirejs.config is already in the app/ directory (in app/main.js), so adding the "baseUrl: 'app'" adds the directory to the path twice.

Comment: Ok, there should not be issues with baseUrl then. Try what @louis suggests in his answer.